How to make a discord bot print my response that I have set
I was trying to make a discord bot that insults my friends, but it keeps telling me that' weight is not defined when I test the code in Discord.
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import random

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Message
load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

permissions = discord.Permissions(administrator=True, send_messages = True, read_messages = True)

def get_response(user_input: str) -> str:
    lowered_input = user_input.lower()
    weight = random.randint(150,1000000)

    if user_input != lowered_input:
        return "LOWERCASE ONLY -100000 Aura, +100000000 pounds."
    # Return a default response if none of the above conditions are met
@bot.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print (f'{bot.user} is now running')


async def on_message(message: Message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    # Get the bot's response based on the user input
    response = get_response(message.content)

    # Send the response back to the channel
    if response:
        await message.channel.send(response)

    # Process commands if you want to add more features later
    await bot.process_commands(message)

    #Incoming Messages:
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message: Message):
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
    username = str(message.author)
    user_message = message.content
    channel = str(message.channel)

    print(f'[{channel}] {username}: "{user_message}"')
async def weight_command(ctx):
    weight = random.randint(150, 1000000)
    await ctx.send(f" your weight is {weight} pounds.")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)

This should have told me that the user is a certain amount of pounds, right? But when I put into discord the line, ?weight, it says that weight is not defined.
I'm honestly so confused. Yes, I double checked the bot's permission, and yes the key is valid, what should I do?

You're running the command ?weight, while the actual command is ?weight_command. You're also not placing a decorator on the function you want to use for the command.
Snippet from your code with additions:
@bot.command() # The command's decorator
async def weight_command(ctx): # The command's name, "weight_command"
    ...

